# Glitch in Stack Jobs search

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs

Inside stackoverflow jobs page, after searching a city, it is impossible for me to change the distance after the search. I am using firefox 42.

In the search panel:

```
1. put in a city
2. search
3. try to change the distance by selecting another distance
4. box closes unexpectedly
```

Comment: I will add that the changing the distance after a search works for me with Chrome 47